# Convert Json in an array of array

Tags: arrays, json, scala, playframework

I need to convert this json (that i take from an rdd spark like a JsonString value)

```
[
  {
    "Quantita": 6,
    "Provincia": "BARI",
    "GENERE": "Avventura"
  },

  {
    "Quantita": 30,
    "Provincia": "BARI",
    "GENERE": "Storia"
  },
  {
    "Quantita": 6,
    "Provincia": "MODUGNO",
    "GENERE": "Avventura"
  },

  {
    "Quantita": 6,
    "Provincia": "MODUGNO",
    "GENERE": "Storia"
  },
  {
    "Quantita": 8,
    "Provincia": "MODUGNO",
    "GENERE": "Avventura"
  }]
```

in an array like this:

```
[
    ['Bari','Avventura',6],
    ['Bari','Storia',30],
    ['Modugno','Avventura',6],
    ['Modugno','Giallo',6],
    ['Modugno','Storia',6],
    ['Avventura','Bari',6],
    ['Avventura','Modugno',6],
    ['Storia','Bari',30],
    ['Storia','Modugno',6]
]
```

I use play framework and i try to make a case class like this

```
case class Libro_D(
    quantita: Int, 
    provincia: String, 
    genere: String   
    )
```

Then i use the read method:

```
implicit val recordReads: Reads[Libro_D] = (
      (JsPath \ "Quantita").read[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "Provincia").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "GENERE").read[String]
      )(Libro_D.apply _)
```

And i create a list like this:

```
val parsedJson = Json.parse(JString_D.stripMargin)

    implicit val f = Json.format[Libro_D]
     println(parsedJson.validate[List[Libro_D]] match {
      case JsSuccess(value, _) => value.map { record => s"""[${record.provincia},${record.genere},${record.quantita}]\n"""}.mkString("[", ",", "]")
      case JsError(_) => println("")
    })
```

So i have a problem. When i println the list, is empty. Why?
Somebody can help me? I use Scala Play framework

Answer (score 0):

If you need only in transform json see [JSON transformers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonTransformers).

Simple transformation helps you:

```
val t = __.read[List[JsArray]](
  list(
    __.read[JsObject].map(o => 
      List((o \ "Provincia").get, (o \ "GENERE").get, (o \ "Quantita").get)
    ).map(JsArray)    
  )
).map(JsArray)

json.transform(t)

scala> res9: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsArray] = JsSuccess([["BARI","Avventura",6],["BARI","Storia",30],["MODUGNO","Avventura",6],["MODUGNO","Storia",6],["MODUGNO","Avventura",8]],)
```

Answer (score -1):

`parsedJson` is not a `List[Libro_D]`. It is a `play.api.libs.json.JsArray`. Change your code to `parsedJson.validate[JsArray]`. In case of `JsSuccess`, print an appropriate message (because the `value.map` will not work)